# Mapstruct dynamic source to target mapping

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

I have to map one of the dto to the target model. How can I map source to target based upon suffix prefix

for example I have to do below

```
@Mapping(source = "dto.balanceSheetInfoDto.assets.value", target = "assetsValue")
@Mapping(source = "dto.balanceSheetInfoDto.assets.isNA", target = "assetsIsNA")
@Mapping(source = "dto.balanceSheetInfoDto.assets.note", target = "assetsNote")

@Mapping(source = "dto.balanceSheetInfoDto.liquidAssets.value", target = "liquidAssetsValue")
@Mapping(source = "dto.balanceSheetInfoDto.liquidAssets.isNA", target = "liquidAssetsIsNA")
@Mapping(source = "dto.balanceSheetInfoDto.liquidAssets.note", target = "liquidAssetsNote")
```

How can I avoid doing this repeatedly for different fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not tied to MapStruct, and if it is not too late for that, I think ModelMapper is better suited for what you need. It does exactly what you describe here, out of the box.

See : http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/#mapping

Comment: What if we are? A simple solution for mapping like `@Mapping(source="{field}", target="with{field}")` would be great